# Intermediate types from a custom mapped type

Tags: typescript

I have created a mapped type for explicitly disallowing certain object/interface properties. The reason is that Typescript's excess property checking only applies when an object literal is assigned directly, and not when it's first assigned to a variable.

See "Excess Property Checks" https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

I have some functions that take an object that must not contain some specific, known, properties. Again, this can be resolved by passing in an object literal, but this can easily be missed by the next developer, so I figured it would be nice to block it out completely (I do realize that I should check the object for excess props at runtime, but my question is only related to TS).

**My primary question** is if it's possible to write the `Disallow` type so that I can make intermediate types from it, such as `DisallowBandC`?

A secondary question is if `Disallow` can be achieved without creating a union of two types? Other simplifications welcome as well.

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

type Never<T, K extends keyof T> = { readonly [P in K]?: never };

// Can this be achieved without a union?
type Disallow<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Never<T, K>;

interface Stuff {
  readonly a: string;
  readonly b?: number;
  readonly c: string | null;
  readonly d: null;
  readonly e?: null;
  readonly f?: undefined;
  readonly g: string;
}

type Blocked = 'b' | 'c'

// This works
export type Disallowed = Disallow<Stuff, Blocked>;

// This does not work:
export type DisallowBandC<T> = Disallow<T, Blocked>;

// TS Error:
// "Type 'Blocked' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof T'.
//  Type '"b"' is not assignable to type 'keyof T'."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a constraint where the values of `K` must be keys of `T`.  To lift this constraint, you can make these changes:

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

// don't need T at all here
type Never<K extends keyof any> = { readonly [P in K]?: never };

// don't need to restrict K to keys of T
type Disallow<T, K extends keyof any> = Omit<T, K> & Never<K>;
```

This will now work:

```
export type DisallowBandC<T> = Disallow<T, Blocked>;
```

Note that since you've lifted the constraint that `K extends keyof T`, you are free to specify a `T` that doesn't contain `Blocked` keys at all:

```
type IsThisOkay = DisallowBandC<{foo: string}>; 
// equivalent to {foo: string, b?: never, c?: never}
```

I assume that's what you want, right?

---

For your second question, you're wondering if you can represent `Disallow` without an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) (`&`), not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) (`|`).  The answer is yes, as long as you mean only that the final output doesn't contain a `&` and not that the definition doesn't use intersections at all:

```
type Disallow<T, K extends keyof any> = {
  [P in keyof (Omit<T, K> & Never<K>)]: P extends K ? never : P extends keyof T ? T[P] : never
};
```

Or equivalently, and this makes it painfully obvious that you're definitely using that same intersected type in the definition:

```
type Disallow<T, K extends keyof any> = {
  [P in keyof (Omit<T, K> & Never<K>)]: (Omit<T, K> & Never<K>)[P]
}
```

This is essentially equivalent, except it is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which iterates over the keys of `Omit<T, K> & Never<K>`.  These are the same as `K | keyof T` but using the intersection has the advantage of making this a [homomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism) mapped type where TypeScript preserves the `readonly` and optional nature of any keys from `T`.  Let's make sure:

```
type TryItOut = DisallowBandC<Stuff>;
```

This inspects as

```
type TryItOut = {
    readonly a: string;
    readonly d: null;
    readonly e?: null | undefined;
    readonly f?: undefined;
    readonly g: string;
    readonly b?: undefined;
    readonly c?: undefined;
}
```

Looks good to me.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This is awesome. You really saved my day (week)!

Comment: It occurs to me we could solve the error by using `type DisallowBandC<T extends Partial<Record<Blocked, any>>> = Disallow<T, Blocked>` but either solution works. Great answer as ususal :)